# How to dismiss a UIPicker that is connected to a UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield, uipickerview, uipicker

I have a `UITextField`, and when pushed a `UIPickerView` comes up to choose a value. How do I get the `UIPickerView` to dismiss once a value is chosen. Someone in another thread told me to `resignFirstResponder` the textfield, but my code isn't working. Any ideas? NOTE: I have two text fields and UI Pickers, that's why I have the 'if' 'else' statement.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.ageTextField)
    {
        [ageTextField resignFirstResponder];
        [agePickerView removeFromSuperview];
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        [relationshipTextField resignFirstResponder];
        [relationshipPickerView removeFromSuperview];
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: UIPicker has nothing to do with textFieldShouldReturn or resignFirstResponder. If you are displaying picker in popover, dismiss it or if you are pushing picker pop it.

Comment: @Rahul I agree completely. +1 to your comment

Comment: For resignFirstResponder to work you have to assign the picker to the textfield's inputView property :)

Comment: use `setInputAccessoryView:` or `setInputView:` properties of textField

Comment: Hey Rahul, how would I dismiss it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code which may solve your problem.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
 {
     if (textField == self.ageTextField) 
     {
         [ageTextField resignFirstResponder];
     } 
     else 
     {
         [relationshipTextField resignFirstResponder];
     }
     [pickerView removeFromSuperview];
     return YES; 
 }
```

or resign your keyboard on following method of `UIPickerView`.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Comment: It didn't work. There were a couple errors with [pickerView removeFromSuperview].

Comment: pickerView means the view on which you populating the UIPickerView.

Comment: Ok, I tried it and it still didn't work. Maybe I'm not testing it correctly in the simulator. What would I have to click in the simulator for the UI Picker to dismiss?

Comment: I tried with the same way as per your question & works fine for me may be you are missing something. I tried it when you tell me that I have couple of errors please check again & let me know.

Comment: Hey Grish, I edited my code to what I added into the program. Would that work? Also, in the simulator, what would I have to click for the UI Picker to dismiss? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try resigning the UITextField in UIPickerViewDelegate method as follows.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    [self.ageTextField resignFirstResponder];
    pickerView.hidden = YES; //Show the pickerview again when you neeed it
}
```

Comment: When I implement your code the UI Picker doesn't come up at all when I click the UI Textfield. Maybe I'm putting it in the wrong place though.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the UIPickerViewDelegate protocol and implement the following method:

```
- (void) pickerView: (UIPickerView*) pickerView
       didSelectRow: (NSInteger)     row
        inComponent: (NSInteger)     component
{
  [self.ageTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```